# BeautifulSoup to parse soundcloud followers

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a soundcloud page and get the links and usernames off of an accounts "followers" page.

I have tried the following but I do not get any links that have what I want

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\marco\\Downloads\\geckodriver- 
v0.23.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe")

driver.get("https:////soundcloud.com/marco-valencia/followers")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

print(soup.find_all("a"))
```

I would like to find all the "a" of class "userBadgeListItem__image" and extract the href string and the corresponding link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For BeautifulSoup to find `a` element with the class

```
soup.find_all("a", class_="userBadgeListItem__image")
```

But for now let only use Selenium. The class `userBadgeListItem__image` has no anchor text change it to `userBadgeListItem__heading`

```
driver.get("https://..............")

# scroll down to get all followers
while True:
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
    time.sleep(3) # wait ajax request
    try:
        # loop until this loading element removed from the page
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.loading.regular.m-padded')
    except: break

# finally extract the followers
followers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('userBadgeListItem__heading')
for f in followers:
    print('%s: %s' % (f.text, f.get_attribute('href')))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  for some reason, when I use your first beautiful soup example, nothing is found or printed.  Your example using selenium only worked quite well though.  Any idea what makes beautiful soup not work?

Comment: its dynamic page using only bs4 will not work and it bad idea if you mix it with selenium because bs4 is simulate what selenium or browser do.